# Organisation of database for stackoverflow type website

Tags: database

I want to make a website on the lines of stackoverflow. I need some suggestions on how do I organise my databases....like what fields should there be for each user, how to organise the questions asked and the replies to them,the votes they get....if anyone can help me with the required database tables and respective fields in them. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for yourself:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Or download and experiment with some of the SO clones:

http://www.osqa.net/

List of clones:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 0):

im not an arrogant a-hole or anything, but that all depends on what you want to optimize for effeciency.  You want us to tell you what a DBA would to do make a website like this.

The only knowledge i can part with my years of experience designing websites and as a software engineer.

Determine every variable and subasset your system will need.  WHat will you require of the users, and need to maintain.  AFterwards, get our some postit notes, and go to a whiteboard.

When you figure out your table schema, post it back here so we can help you optimize.  IMO, you arent asking a question as asking for something for free.

It is a lengthy process.  When YOU figure out how you want the tables, we can adjust all your varchars, and bits, and clobs to be the best.

Until then, I wish you luck.

Sidenote:  I have had to do this from scratch with a team of 5 to figure out and design a project.  Just sit down 1 day and determine every thing you want to accomplish and then as your sticky notes can be moved around, Do that to figure out what you think would go well together.